# How to insert variable in Laravel URL generation

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a simple CRUD application using Laravel With Ajax. To edit a record, I have to fetch data from the following URL.

```
/AjaxCrudApp/public/contacts/1/edit
```

How can I fetch the data from the above URL by using Ajax?

**Ajax**

```
<script>
    var id = $(this).data('contact');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "{{ URL("contacts/here i want to put the var ID/edit") }}",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#modal").append(data);
            $("#editContact").modal('show');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Do I have to pass a variable in the URL generation?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve it with something like this:

```
var url = "{{ URL('contacts/{id}/edit') }}".replace('{id}', $(this).data('contact')); 

$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url: url,
    success:function(data){
        $("#modal").append(data);
        $("#editContact").modal('show');
    }
});
```